# Woocommerce hook before order status change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, workflow, orders

I've been searching for a hook that is triggered before the order status is changed or, for that matter, before the order is updated.

I'm trying to enforce a designed workflow. I've been able to change the options the users have to change the order status so they don't choose a 'wrong' status, but I want to check the updates using code too (never trust user input).

There are hooks triggered after the status has changed (woocommerce_order_status[to]) that do not prevent 'illegal' status changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is this action which you could hook into: [`woocommerce_order_status_changed`](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/actions/woocommerce_order_status_changed/) The 2nd and 3rd variables returned are the previous and the new status respectively.

Although it still happens after the change, you can at least test for the change and revert the status back.

Hope that helps

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and checked this solution. In my case, a plugin is used that can automatically register an order with a delivery service when setting a special status. As you can guess, I absolutely do not need to register this package in case of a negative check of this order.